# Virtual Box. Выделенный IP для гостевой ОС.

Tags: virtual

Windows 7 как хостовая ОС, Ubuntu server на Virtual Box - как гостевая. По умолчанию гостевая ОС подключается к сети через NAT. Нужно, чтобы гостевая машина подключалась к сети напрямую (адреса в сети раздаются по DHCP либо можно указать самостоятельно). 
Как настроить?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ найден - просто поставить сеть бриджом :)